# RunProcess returns a confusing error message when using ProcessDirectory options

Tags: files-and-directories, scripting

Here is one way to find the names of the files in one's home directory:

```
FileNames["*", "~"]
(* { "~/.account", "~/Applications", "~/.bash_sessions", ... } *)
```

Here is another way:

```
RunProcess[{"ls"}, ProcessDirectory -> "/Users/pillsy"]
(*  <|"ExitCode" -> 0, 
      "StandardOutput" -> "Applications
    Desktop...", "StandardError" -> ""|> *)
```

This is not a way to find the names of the files in one's home directory:

```
RunProcess[{"ls"}, ProcessDirectory -> "~"]
(* RunProcess::pnfd: Program ls not found.  Check Environment["PATH"]. 
   $Failed *)
```

This is weird, both the lack of the expansion of the `~` and the completely mystifying error message. I'm not even sure how to conveniently expand that `~` to an absolute file name that works.

Comment: `ExpandFileName` will expand `~`

Answer (score 4):

This is documented very clearly in the [RunProcess](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RunProcess.html#1662325797) documentation page...

> Special symbols like ~ and * are not converted using shell expansion because RunProcess skips the shell:

If you want to access this programmatically, consider `$HomeDirectory`:

```
RunProcess[{"ls"}, ProcessDirectory -> $HomeDirectory]
```